# How can I group data from csv by ID and other specific columns and perform operations like sum using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to derive some analytics for a set of data that I have on a csv file. The csv file has the following format[sniped from csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdAnd.png)

The first column contains an ID/schema, each other column represents time/generations. This happens N number of Runs.

I want to be able to the occurrence of each ID/schema at each point of time/generations. So that I can have a final count of each ID, a final average, and a final standard deviation from the N number of runs.

So far I am able to extract the data, and remove the rows that contain 'R'. I don't really care about the runs because I want to add them together.

First step is to at least sum all the runs per each ID and generation but I can't seem to get the hang of pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
def main():
    filename = 'out/outputs.csv'  # Replace with the actual filename
    rdata = read_csv(filename)
    data = pd.DataFrame(rdata)
    data = data[~data[0].str.contains('R')]
    sums = data.groupby(data[0],axis=1) # here is where I want to sum by schema/ID and generation
    sums = sums.sum()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

At the end my goal is to have something like the following matrices

```
sums
| Schema | gen1 | gen2 | genN|
|--------|------|------|-----|
| 11**** |    5 |  10  |  100|
| ***111 |    0 |  3   |  12 |

averages
|Schema | gen1 | gen2 | genN |
|-------|------|------|------|
|11**** | 6.0  | 12.1 | 120.2|
|***111 | 0.0  | 10.0 | 30.0 |

standard deviations
|Schema | gen1 | gen2 | genN |
|-------|------|------|------|
|11**** |  0.2 |   1.0|  0.1 |
|***111 |  0.0 |   0.3|  0.12|
```

EDIT:
[matrices loose their form but here is the example result I would like to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca4Kd.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide a [mre]. Add the data sample directly to your question body as *text*, not as a picture. Show both input *and* expected output (i.e. the *actual* output based on the input provided). E.g., use `data.to_dict()`, downsize the sample, and post in a block between triple backticks (```).

Comment: Please do not upload pictures of data (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Rather create a sample df via code. (e.g. you could `print(df.head().to_dict()`)